# Connecting to Polygon network with OpenEthereum

Tags: blockchain, polygon, openethereum

Have anyone already managed to connect OpenEthereum node to Polygon (mainnet or Mumbai testnet)?
I seems to be technically possible.

I need some kind of `genesis.json` file for these networks along with bootstrap nodes list.

Comment: I'm also looking into this. I've only so far tested with Geth Ethereum clients. Have you made any further attempts?

Comment: Unfortunately it is impossible. Polygon network has it's own consensus algorithm implemented in Heimdal service. OpenEthereum is not capable of connecting to Polygon at least now.